# Php Mysql Insert Array in columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have the follow problem:
I have differents arrays, each array contain a list of items.
I try to insert in database but each item of list result togheter.

This is my code:
(i use preg_replace for delete 
 between items)

```
$codice = preg_replace('/(<br>)+$/', '', $_POST['jcitemcodice']);
$prodotto = preg_replace('/(<br>)+$/', '', $_POST['jcitemname']);
$quantita = preg_replace('/(<br>)+$/', '', $_POST['jcitemqty']);
$prezzo = preg_replace('/(<br>)+$/', '', $_POST['jcitemprezzo']);

$a1 = array("$codice","$prodotto","$quantita","$prezzo");

$res = implode("','" ,$a1);

$sql = "INSERT INTO test (codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES ('$res')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Making echo of query the result is:

```
INSERT INTO test (codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES ('SUT03M SUT02M','Arrabbiata Albahaca','12 6','1.25 1.3')
```

but for to be correct i need the result:

```
INSERT INTO test (codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES ('SUT03M','Arrabbiata','12','1.25'), VALUES ('SUT02M','Albahaca','6','1.3')

$codice contain: SUT03M SUT02M
$prodotto contain: Arrabbiata Albahaca
$quantita contain: 12 6
$prezzo contain: 1.25 1.3
```

I have try a lot of codes looking around but always same result.

Thanks you.

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming `codice, prodotto, quantita, prezzo` don't contain value with **_** (underscore), you can explode their content separated by it:

```
//Change existing tag with defined delimiter
$d = "_";//delimiter
$codice = preg_replace('#<[^>]+>#', $d, $_POST['jcitemcodice']);
$prodotto = preg_replace('#<[^>]+>#', $d, $_POST['jcitemname']);
$quantita = preg_replace('#<[^>]+>#', $d, $_POST['jcitemqty']);
$prezzo = preg_replace('#<[^>]+>#', $d, $_POST['jcitemprezzo']);

//replace space in quantita and in prezzo with the delimiter
$quantita = preg_replace(' ', $d, $quantita);
$prezzo = preg_replace(' ', $d, $prezzo);

//Separate data
$tCodice = explode($d, $codice);
$tProdotto = explode($d, $prodotto);
$tQuantita = explode($d, $quantita);
$tPrezzo = explode($d, $prezzo);

//Formulate values string
$values = "";
foreach($tCodice as $key => $_codice){
    if($_codice > ""){
         $a1 = array(trim($tCodice[$key]), trim($tProdotto[$key]), trim($tQuantita[$key]), trim($tPrezzo[$key]));
         $res = implode("','" ,$a1);
         if($values != ""){
             $values .= ", ";
         }
         $values .= "('".$res."')";
    }
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES $values";
echo $sql;
```

Please improve this for more custom data from you $_POST

Comment: Still problem in insert

INSERT INTO test (codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES ('SUT03M
SUT02M','Arrabbiata
Albahaca','12
6','1.25
1.3')


in the db appear:

+------------------+----------------------------------+------------+---------+
|   codice          |        prodotto                     | quantita | prezzo |
+------------------+----------------------------------+------------+---------+
| SUT03M<br> | Arrabbiata<br>Albahaca | 12<br>6  |  1.25  |
+------------------+----------------------------------+------------+---------+ 

Thanks you

Comment: ah, I see, there are some remaining tags, I updated my answer. Please re-test

Comment: Now is better, but error:

INSERT INTO test (codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES ('SUT03M','Arrabbiata','12','1.25')('SUT02M','Albahaca','6','1.3')('','','','')



Error: INSERT INTO test (codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES ('SUT03M','Arrabbiata','12','1.25')('SUT02M','Albahaca','6','1.3')('','','','')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('SUT02M','Albahaca','6','1.3')('','','','')' at line 1

thanks you

Comment: haha, just add a ctrl to check void character before adding it into `$values`, eg:  `if($_codice > "")`. Updated, re-check again

Comment: With ctrl is ok, now it is only missed the comma between values parentesis )( must be ),(

INSERT INTO test (codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES ('SUT03M','Arrabbiata','12','1.25')('SUT02M','Albahaca','6','1.3')

SUT03MSUT02M

Error: INSERT INTO test (codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES ('SUT03M','Arrabbiata','12','1.25')('SUT02M','Albahaca','6','1.3')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('SUT02M','Albahaca','6','1.3')' at line 1

Comment: note I changed the `if($value != "")` to `if($values != "")` [missed `s` in the first). Did you have that ?

Comment: I have changed now, and the comma is between ),(  but put another comma to the end of the line

INSERT INTO test (codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES ('SUT03M','Arrabbiata','12','1.25'), ('SUT02M','Albahaca','6','1.3'), 

SUT03MSUT02M

Error: INSERT INTO test (codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES ('SUT03M','Arrabbiata','12','1.25'), ('SUT02M','Albahaca','6','1.3'), 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Work perfectly now. I have copied again your code and all work fine.

INSERT INTO test (codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES ('SUT02M','Albahaca','6','1.3'), ('SUT03M','Arrabbiata','6','1.25')

But now i have the last question. Some products names are composed from more words, like Pesto alla Genovese.
When i try to add it and insert, keep only the first word Pesto. or if i add two product, show like this:

INSERT INTO test (codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES ('SUT08M','Pesto','6','2.3'), ('SUT02M','alla','6','1.3')

There is a way to fix it otr you suggest something?

Comment: use another delimiter (not space), ex : `$d = "_";//delimiter`. Re-copy paste the code and check

Comment: Is fantastic. You have made a perfect goal.
All work fine.
Thanks you very mutch.

Comment: there was just one error I think, change `$prezzo = preg_replace(' ', $d, $quantita);` to `$prezzo = preg_replace(' ', $d, $prezzo);`.

Comment: If I add
$quantita = preg_replace(' ', $d, $quantita);
$prezzo = preg_replace(' ', $d, $prezzo);

quantita and prezzo disappear when insert.

All work fine with the previous.

Thanks you.

Answer (score -1):

This is a generalized code and no matter how many variables u have and it will add null if no match found in the strings u were already split.

```
$codice = "SUT03M SUT02M";
$prodotto = "Arrabbiata";
$quantita = "12 6";
$prezzo = "1.25 1.3";
$column_keys = array("codice","prodotto","quantita","prezzo");

$res = array();
$c = 0;
$sql = "";
$max = array("k" => 0,"v" => "");
foreach ($column_keys as $key => $value) {
    $res[$value] = explode(" ",${$value});
    $c = count($res[$value]);
    if($c > $max["k"])
       $max = array("k" => $c,"v" => $value); 
}
if($max["k"] > 0){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test (".implode($column_keys,",").") VALUES ";
    for ($i=0; $i < $max["k"] ; $i++) { 
        $ar = array();
        foreach ($column_keys as $key => $value)
            $ar[] = isset($res[$value][$i]) ? $res[$value][$i] : "NULL";
        $adstrng = $i>0 ? ",":"";
        $sql.= $adstrng."(".implode($ar,",").")";
    }    
}
echo $sql;
```

> As like @tadman commented don't use deprecated codes and try to do in
>   updated standards like PDO

Comment: Hello. With you code I have:

INSERT INTO (codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES (SUT03M
SUT02M,Arrabbiata
Albahaca,12
6,1.25
1.3)INSERT INTO (codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES (SUT03M
SUT02M,Arrabbiata
Albahaca,12
6,1.25
1.3)

Error: INSERT INTO (codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES (SUT03M
SUT02M,Arrabbiata
Albahaca,12
6,1.25
1.3)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES (SUT03M
SUT02M,Arrabbiata
Albahac' at line 1

Thanks you

Comment: The result above is when i use:

$codice = preg_replace('/(<br>)+$/', '', $_POST['jcitemcodice']);
$prodotto = preg_replace('/(<br>)+$/', '', $_POST['jcitemname']);
$quantita = preg_replace('/(<br>)+$/', '', $_POST['jcitemqty']);
$prezzo = preg_replace('/(<br>)+$/', '', $_POST['jcitemprezzo']);

Comment: If i use your integral code o have:

INSERT INTO (codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES (SUT03M,Arrabbiata,12,1.25),(SUT02M,Albahaca,6,1.3)INSERT INTO (codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES (SUT03M,Arrabbiata,12,1.25),(SUT02M,Albahaca,6,1.3)

Error: INSERT INTO (codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES (SUT03M,Arrabbiata,12,1.25),(SUT02M,Albahaca,6,1.3)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(codice,prodotto,quantita,prezzo) VALUES (SUT03M,Arrabbiata,12,1.25),(SUT02M,Alb' at line 1

Comment: Making echo of variables posted without preg_replace i have:

echo $_POST['jcitemcodice'];
echo $_POST['jcitemname'];
echo $_POST['jcitemqty'];
echo $_POST['jcitemprezzo'];

SUT03M
SUT02M
Arrabbiata
Albahaca
12
6
1.25
1.3

each line end with <br> tag

Comment: echo $_POST['jcitemcodice'];
SUT03M<br>
SUT02M<br>

echo $_POST['jcitemname'];
Arrabbiata<br>
Albahaca<br>

echo $_POST['jcitemqty'];
12<br>
6<br>

echo $_POST['jcitemprezzo'];
1.25<br>
1.3<br>

Comment: table name was missing..in query

Comment: use strip_tags($_POST['jcitemcodice']) and try to escape from injuctions